# Change page in Tkinter after a fixed time

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to automatic change pages according to a fixed time in Tkinter?
For example:
I have 3 pages (`page1`, `page2`, `page3`). I need to:

1. show page1 for 5 second
2. show page2 to for 5 second
3. show page3 to for 5 second

And then again page 1...
It is posible?
Thank You in advice for the help

Comment: Look into the tkinter `.after` method https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method

Answer (score 0):

All tkinter widgets have a method named `after` which can be configured to call functions in the future. It takes an argument representing milliseconds, a function to call, and arguments to pass to the function.

Assuming you have a root window named `root`, and assuming you have a function called `show_page` which takes an argument, you can schedule the page switching once for each page with the following:

```
root.after(5000, show_page, page1)
root.after(10000, show_page, page2)
root.after(15000, show_page, page3)
```

If you want a continuous loop, you can create a single function which iterates over a list. [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) makes it easy to continually iterate over a list.

Since you didn't provide a [mcve], here's a fully working example which uses a label to simulate a page, and uses `itertools.cycle` to continually cycle through the pages every five seconds.

```
import tkinter as tk
import itertools

def show_page(page):
    label.configure(text=page)

def cycle_page(pages):
    page = next(pages)
    show_page(page)
    root.after(5000, cycle_page, pages)

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="", width=20)
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

pages = itertools.cycle(["page1", "page2", "page3"])
cycle_page(pages)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for example. What if I have a 3 page with some label, canvas, etc, and I would like to change it automaticly?

Comment: @user3162643: I don't understand your question. there's nothing preventing you from doing that. You can use `after` to schedule any function you want to be called in the future.